# how to make a file to open in a particular editor in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have many types of file in my eclipse workspace, so i want some files to be open in a particular editor. say a war or a jar with winrar. sql with some eql developer, xml,s with xml editor etc how to set that? so that whenever i open them, they should open a assigned editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is an entry in the eclipse preferences that associates file types with editors.  You select your file type (e.g *.html) and assign it one of your installed editors.

On Mac OS, the preference you want is:
Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations.

Comment: With Darren's approach you can set defaults and add/remove editors. You can also do this individually for files within your project: Right click > Open With...

Comment: Is it possible to do with code.i.e. whenever i open any editor it should open in default editor.

Answer (score 1):

Goto

Window-Preferences

then

General->Editor->fileAssociations navigation

then

select or add the extension in the right top dialog

then click add on the right bottom dialog, select the appropriate application and save :-)

Answer (score 0):

You want to add an entry in the Preferences for General->Editors->File Associations.